# when i try to activate my Virtual Environment its trows an error

Tags: python, django, pip, command, python-venv

`**when i try to activate my venv its throw an error like " The module 'myworld' could not be loaded"**`

PS D:\Django> myworld\Scripts\activate.dat
myworld\Scripts\activate.dat : The module 'myworld' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
myworld'.
At line:1 char:1

- myworld\Scripts\activate.dat
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (myworld\\Scripts\\activate.dat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
  ```

##Solution For This Error??

> ! PS D:\Django> myworld\Scripts\activate.dat
> (myworld) C:\Users\Your Name>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on windows,
I think it's better to use command prompt instead of PowerShell.

Also use virutalenv wrapper, its mush easy and convenient to handle virtual env via wrapper.

[check this out](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/)